# why use a method with no parameter lists over a val

Tags: scala

I came across this function in Scala `def nullable: Boolean = true`. I understand what does this function do, but I want to know is there specific name for this kind of function, and what's the motivation not using `var`

Comment: Your question is badly-titled. This is not a "function without a body". This is a method, with no parameter lists, with a body. You should probably reword it. I think you might be asking "why would I use a method with no parameter lists over a val?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, I would be very precise in scala: use the word *Function* to only ever mean an instance of `FunctionN` and use the word *Method* when talking about a `def` (which may have zero or more parameter lists). Secondly, this most definitely *does have a body* (albeit not enclosed in braces). Its body is the expression `true` (i.e. a boolean literal).

I assume that you really mean to ask: *"why use a method with no parameter lists over a val?"*

When deciding whether to represent some property of your class, you can choose between a method and a value (advice: avoid using `var`). Often, if the property involves no side effects, we can use a def with no parameter lists (the scala idiom is that a def with a single, empty parameter list implies side-effects).

Hence we may choose any of the following, all of which are semantically equivalent at the use-site (except for performance characteristics):

```
case class Foo(s: String) {
  //Eager - we calculate and store the value regardless of whether
  //        it is ever used 
  val isEmpty = s.isEmpty
}

case class Foo(s: String) {
  //Lazy - we calculate and store the value when it
  //       it is first used 
  lazy val isEmpty = s.isEmpty
}

case class Foo(s: String) {
  //Non-strict - we calculate the value each time
  //             it is used 
  def isEmpty = s.isEmpty
}
```

Hence we might take the following advice

- If the value is computationally **expensive** to calculate and we are sure we will use it multiple times, use `val`
- If the value is computationally expensive and we may use it zero or many times, use `lazy val`
- If the value is space-expensive and we think it will be generally used a most once, use `def`

However, there is an additional consideration; using a `val` (or `lazy val`) is likely to be **of benefit to debugging** using an IDE which generally can show you in an *inspection* window the value of any in-scope `val`s

Comment: "Firstly, I would be very precise in scala: use the word _Function_ to only ever mean an instance of `FunctionN` and use the word _Method_ when talking about a `def` (which may have zero or more parameter lists)." – If only the SLS adhered to that advice …

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference of the use of `def` or `var/val` is the when the value will be executed.

- the `def` defines a name for a value, the value on the right will be executed when it is called (called by name), meaning it is lazy
- and `var` defines a name for a value, and it is execute it's evaluated, eagerly upon definition